# How to send a MVC Model in a Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing challenges for posting a Model to invoke an action in a controller.

i have a main view where i make a web service call and with certain criteria and get the results.Once i have the results i am showing the results into a partial view as a pop up on the original view and then in the partial view pop i have  a search button which should search in the results shown in the partial view.So for this i need to send the model to the controller to search in the results set that is being displayed in the partial view.

Can this be achieved 
How can be this achieved ?

Need your help guys....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In my understanding you have results display on the page and when the user searches that page will only show the result based on his keyword or criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really get why you have problem here. If your controller action looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult index(int param1, string param2...) 
{

}
```

You need to do POST request to this action with parameters specified. So request body will have `param1=123&param2=somestring&...`
Or using JSON: `{"param1": 123, "param2":"somestring"...}`. Almost same thing for GET request.

ajax call itself can look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your_url',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(your_model),
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```